# How to avoid gaps in mesh when using smooth

Tags: mesh, smooth

I downloaded this hat mesh online, and it is originally polygonal.

I want it to be smooth, so I use the smooth tool and....[image]

It turns into some weird web of faces. The only solution I thought of is painstakingly selecting EVERY edge, and pressing "F" to close the gap.

Is there a way I can fill the gaps automatically, or prevent this from happening when I use the smooth tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the faces are separate from one another. You can join them together by going into edit mode on the original mesh, selecting all, and then doing “Merge -> By distance”. Smooth should then work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it!

Comment: @Diio Your welcome. PTL!